# Can anyone please explain the output of the following program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    typedef int x[2];
    x myArray[3] = {1, 2, 3, 4};//line 1
    printf("\n%u", sizeof(myArray)); //line 2
    printf("\n%d", myArray[1][0]);//line 3

    return 0;
}
```

Output :

24

3

Can anyone explain how line 3 gives output 3

Comment: Note that the first `printf` uses the wrong format for a `sizeof` value.  It should be `%zu`.  Otherwise there's a potential size mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> typedef int x[2];
> x myArray[3] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
> ```

is the same as

```
int myarray[3][2] = {
    {1, 2}, // myarray[0][0], myarray[0][1]
    {3, 4}, // myarray[1][0], myarray[1][1]
    {0, 0}, // myarray[2][0], myarray[2][1]
};
```